# Generating a table from google sheet ranges to google docs only if there is data in the first cell of each row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my google scrip that pulls information from a google sheet and generates an invoice from a template.

```
function Invoice2() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let overview = ss.getSheetByName("Overview");
  let ssn = ss.getSheetByName(ss.getRange("F13").getDisplayValue());


  // Template and folder details
  let templateID = overview.getRange("H20").getDisplayValue();
  let folderidID = overview.getRange("H19").getDisplayValue();
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderidID);
  
  // File name
  let namedata = overview.getRange("C19").getDisplayValue();
  let monthdata = ssn.getRange("F13").getDisplayValue();
  let yeardata = overview.getRange("F14").getDisplayValue();
  let fileName = namedata + ' ' + monthdata + ' ' + "Invoice" + ' ' + yeardata;
  
  // Rates and hours
  let sessionHourlyRate = ssn.getRange("G2").getDisplayValue();
  let opwHourlyRate = ssn.getRange("G6").getDisplayValue();
  let sessionhours = ssn.getRange("G3").getDisplayValue();
  let otherPaidWorkHours = ssn.getRange("G7").getDisplayValue();
  
  // Totals
  let stotaldata = ssn.getRange("G4").getDisplayValue();
  let opwtotal = ssn.getRange("G8").getDisplayValue();
  let allTotal = ssn.getRange("G11").getDisplayValue();
  
  // Bank details
  let bankName = overview.getRange("D19").getDisplayValue();
  let sortCode = overview.getRange("E19").getDisplayValue();
  let accountNumber = overview.getRange("F19").getDisplayValue();

  // Copy the template and open it as a document
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID);
  let copy = file.makeCopy(fileName, folder);
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  let body = doc.getBody();
  
  // Replace text placeholders with values from the spreadsheet
  body.replaceText('<NAME>', namedata);
  body.replaceText('<MONTH>', monthdata);
  body.replaceText('<YEAR>', yeardata);
  body.replaceText('<HR>', sessionHourlyRate);
  body.replaceText('<OPWHR>', opwHourlyRate);
  body.replaceText('<SHOUR>', sessionhours);
  body.replaceText('<OPWHOUR>', otherPaidWorkHours);
  body.replaceText('<STOTAL>', stotaldata);
  body.replaceText('<OPWTOTAL>', opwtotal);
  body.replaceText('<ALLTOTAL>', allTotal);
  body.replaceText('<BANKNAME>', bankName);
  body.replaceText('<AN>', accountNumber);
  body.replaceText('<SC>', sortCode);

var srcData = ssn.getRange("A1:E50").getDisplayValues();
body.insertParagraph(0, 'Invoice').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  table = body.appendTable(srcData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

The script works but I have a few issues all related to this section of the code

```
var srcData = ssn.getRange("A1:E50").getDisplayValues();
body.insertParagraph(0, 'Invoice').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  table = body.appendTable(srcData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

Firstly, Cell A1 should be "Name" but for some reason it is generating a numerical value. Also, not all the values in the range "A1:E50" are populated, is there a way of adding in 5 standardise headings then pull data from A2:E? As row A1:E are just headings I would like it so the script will only pull in each row A:E if there is a value in cell A of each row. Finally, I would like it to generate an empty column to the right of the table in the doc. I would select the range to be "A1:F50" but F has cells that contain data that isn't relevant to the generated table.

I have tried using this instead

```
var srcData = ssn.getRange("A1:E50,S1:S").getDisplayValues();
body.insertParagraph(0, 'Invoice').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
table = body.appendTable(srcData);
table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
> }
```

As Column S is empty but the script breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with why the name is a number.  `getDisplayValues()` should return a string if the name is a string.  But for the rest try this.

```
// start with row 2
var srcData = ssn.getRange("A2:E50").getDisplayValues();
srcData = srcData.filter( row => row[0] !== "" );
srcData.forEach( row => row.push("") );
```

Reference

- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)